# Unresolved constraint in bundle com.adobe.cq.cq-dialog-conversion

Tags: aem

This issue is related to `Adobe AEM 6.1 (Java 8_45)`. I am trying to convert the classic UI dialogs to `Coral UI/Granite UI`. I have installed "[cq-dialog-conversion-content](https://www.adobeaemcloud.com/content/marketplace/marketplaceProxy.html?packagePath=/content/companies/public/adobe/packages/cq600/tools/cq-dialog-conversion-content)" and ran the conversion tool, this is giving me the below exception:

### Error.log:

```
27.06.2015 21:32:20.786 *ERROR* [qtp970663608-179] org.apache.felix.http.jetty %bundles.pluginTitle: Cannot start (org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Unresolved constraint in bundle com.adobe.cq.cq-dialog-conversion [449]: Unable to resolve 449.0: missing requirement [449.0] osgi.wiring.package; (&(osgi.wiring.package=com.adobe.cq.dialogconversion)(version>=1.0.0)(!(version>=1.1.0))))
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Unresolved constraint in bundle com.adobe.cq.cq-dialog-conversion [449]: Unable to resolve 449.0: missing requirement [449.0] osgi.wiring.package; (&(osgi.wiring.package=com.adobe.cq.dialogconversion)(version>=1.0.0)(!(version>=1.1.0)))
    at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.resolveBundleRevision(Felix.java:4095)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.startBundle(Felix.java:2114)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleImpl.start(BundleImpl.java:977)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleImpl.start(BundleImpl.java:964)
    at org.apache.felix.webconsole.internal.core.BundlesServlet.doPost(BundlesServlet.java:365)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:644)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:725)
    at org.apache.felix.webconsole.internal.servlet.OsgiManager.service(OsgiManager.java:555)
    at org.apache.felix.webconsole.internal.servlet.OsgiManager$3.run(OsgiManager.java:459)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.apache.felix.webconsole.internal.servlet.OsgiManager.service(OsgiManager.java:455)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.handler.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:336)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.handler.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:297)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.ServletPipeline.handle(ServletPipeline.java:93)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.InvocationFilterChain.doFilter(InvocationFilterChain.java:50)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.HttpFilterChain.doFilter(HttpFilterChain.java:31)
    at org.apache.sling.i18n.impl.I18NFilter.doFilter(I18NFilter.java:129)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.handler.FilterHandler.doHandle(FilterHandler.java:108)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.handler.FilterHandler.handle(FilterHandler.java:80)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.InvocationFilterChain.doFilter(InvocationFilterChain.java:46)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.HttpFilterChain.doFilter(HttpFilterChain.java:31)
    at org.apache.sling.security.impl.ReferrerFilter.doFilter(ReferrerFilter.java:290)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.handler.FilterHandler.doHandle(FilterHandler.java:108)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.handler.FilterHandler.handle(FilterHandler.java:80)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.InvocationFilterChain.doFilter(InvocationFilterChain.java:46)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.HttpFilterChain.doFilter(HttpFilterChain.java:31)
    at com.adobe.granite.license.impl.LicenseCheckFilter.doFilter(LicenseCheckFilter.java:308)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.handler.FilterHandler.doHandle(FilterHandler.java:108)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.handler.FilterHandler.handle(FilterHandler.java:80)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.InvocationFilterChain.doFilter(InvocationFilterChain.java:46)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.HttpFilterChain.doFilter(HttpFilterChain.java:31)
    at org.apache.felix.http.sslfilter.internal.SslFilter.doFilter(SslFilter.java:89)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.handler.FilterHandler.doHandle(FilterHandler.java:108)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.handler.FilterHandler.handle(FilterHandler.java:80)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.InvocationFilterChain.doFilter(InvocationFilterChain.java:46)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.HttpFilterChain.doFilter(HttpFilterChain.java:31)
    at org.apache.sling.featureflags.impl.FeatureManager.doFilter(FeatureManager.java:115)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.handler.FilterHandler.doHandle(FilterHandler.java:108)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.handler.FilterHandler.handle(FilterHandler.java:80)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.InvocationFilterChain.doFilter(InvocationFilterChain.java:46)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.HttpFilterChain.doFilter(HttpFilterChain.java:31)
    at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.log.RequestLoggerFilter.doFilter(RequestLoggerFilter.java:75)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.handler.FilterHandler.doHandle(FilterHandler.java:108)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.handler.FilterHandler.handle(FilterHandler.java:80)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.InvocationFilterChain.doFilter(InvocationFilterChain.java:46)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.HttpFilterChain.doFilter(HttpFilterChain.java:31)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.FilterPipeline.dispatch(FilterPipeline.java:76)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.Dispatcher.dispatch(Dispatcher.java:49)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.DispatcherServlet.service(DispatcherServlet.java:67)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:725)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:808)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:587)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:221)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1127)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:515)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:185)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1061)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:215)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:97)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:497)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:310)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:257)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$2.run(AbstractConnection.java:540)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:635)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:555)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

### stderr.log

```
27.06.2015 21:22:17.047 *ERROR* [FelixStartLevel] ERROR: Error starting jcrinstall:/libs/cq/dialogconversion/install/cq-dialog-conversion-1.0.2.jar (org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Unresolved constraint in bundle com.adobe.cq.cq-dialog-conversion [449]: Unable to resolve 449.0: missing requirement [449.0] osgi.wiring.package; (&(osgi.wiring.package=com.adobe.cq.dialogconversion)(version>=1.0.0)(!(version>=1.1.0))))
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Unresolved constraint in bundle com.adobe.cq.cq-dialog-conversion [449]: Unable to resolve 449.0: missing requirement [449.0] osgi.wiring.package; (&(osgi.wiring.package=com.adobe.cq.dialogconversion)(version>=1.0.0)(!(version>=1.1.0)))
    at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.resolveBundleRevision(Felix.java:4095)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.startBundle(Felix.java:2114)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.setActiveStartLevel(Felix.java:1368)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.FrameworkStartLevelImpl.run(FrameworkStartLevelImpl.java:308)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Please help me with my issue.

Answer (score 0):

Check if Dialog conversion bundle (Adobe AEM Dialog Conversioncom.adobe.cq.cq-dialog-conversion) is started or not. Looks like there are unresolved dependencies in this bundle.